# Retrieve array items by key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Somehow, I have managed to create the array below.  Now that the array has been created, can someone explain how I can retrieve such information as:

- total number of elements;
- total number of elements on 2011-11-18;

  ```
  Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                      [2011-11-18 00:00:00] => C
                  )

              [1] => Array
                  (
                      [2011-11-18 00:00:00] => I
                  )

              [2] => Array
                  (
                      [2011-11-18 00:00:00] => S
                  )

          )

      [1] => Array
          (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                      [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => C
                  )

              [1] => Array
                  (
                      [2011-11-22 00:00:00] => S
                  )

          )

  )
  ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

total number of elements

```
 count($array_name, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```

to count the number for a specific key as in your case you can use this , i dont know if there is another better way to do that

```
    $count = 0;
    $date =date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, '11', '22', '2011')); 
    foreach ($array_name as $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $inner) {
            if (isset($inner[$date])) {
                ++$count;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that `count($array_name, COUNT_RECURSIVE)` **will not return 5** in the case that the OP has provided.  It will return 12.  It effectively counts every element for which there is a key, which includes all the arrays along the way.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
foreach($yourArray as $key => $val) {
  echo "Key is:".$key." and value is:".$val."<br />";
}
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but this is the result I got:

Key is:0 and value is:Array
Key is:1 and value is:Array

Answer (score 1):

Your need calcucate this in cycle, as ex in foreach:

```
<?
$arr[0][0]["2011-11-18 00:00:00"] = "C";
$arr[0][1]["2011-11-18 00:00:00"] = "I";
$arr[0][2]["2011-11-18 00:00:00"] = "S";
$arr[1][0]["2011-11-22 00:00:00"] = "C";
$arr[1][1]["2011-11-22 00:00:00"] = "S";


// calc all
$tot = 0;
foreach ($arr as $a1)
  foreach ($a1 as $a)
    $tot ++;
echo "Total: $tot\n<br />"; // echo 5


//Find specific time elem
$tot = 0;
$d_ = "2011-11-18 00:00:00";
foreach ($arr as $a1)
  foreach ($a1 as $a2)
    foreach ($a2 as $a3_k=>$a3_v)
      if ( $a3_k == $d_ )
        $tot ++;
echo "Total of $d_: $tot\n<br />"; // echo 5
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The total number of elements can be retrieved by iterating through each array and summing their `count`s.  You can do this by saying:

```
function get_total_elements() {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($outer_arr as $inner_arr) {
        foreach ($inner_arr as $date_arr) {
            $sum += count($date_arr);
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

To get the total number of elements for a given date, you can just modify it slightly to say:

```
function get_total_elements_for_date($m, $d, $y) {
    date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y));
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($outer_arr as $inner_arr) {
        foreach ($inner_arr as $date_arr) {
            if (isset($date_arr[$date])) {
                $sum++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

Then you can invoke the function by saying (for the example of November 18th, 2011): `get_total_elements_for_date(11, 18, 2011)`.

Comment: Hi Jonathan - Thanks for trying to help me out.  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure out your answer.  I'm still working on it, but in the meantime I have posted another question that may explain my problem a little better:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284302/php-count-items-in-a-multi-dimensional-array