# Count number of leaves in nested array tree

Tags: php, arrays, tree, nested

I have a nested array tree, generated from a flat array with the following function :

```
function convertToTree(array $flat, $idField = 'id',
                        $parentIdField = 'parentId',
                        $childNodesField = 'childNodes') {
    $indexed = array();
    // first pass - get the array indexed by the primary id  
    foreach ($flat as $row) {
        $indexed[$row[$idField]] = $row;
        $indexed[$row[$idField]][$childNodesField] = array();
    }

    //second pass  
    $root = null;
    foreach ($indexed as $id => $row) {
        $indexed[$row[$parentIdField]][$childNodesField][$id] =& $indexed[$id];
        if (!$row[$parentIdField]) {
            $root = $id;
        }

    }
    return array($root => $indexed[$root]);
}
```

I would need to add an entry "NUMBER OF LEAVES" for each node of my array. This entry should count ALL the leaves of all the subnodes of the node :

```
Array ( 
    [9] => Array ( 
        [id] => 9, 
        [parentId] => null,
        [name] => Item 0, 
        [NUMBER OF LEAVES] => 4,  (corresponding to leaves 100 and 101 + 200 and 201)
        [childNodes] => Array 
            ( 
                [1] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 1, 
                    [parentId] => 9, 
                    [name] => Item 1, 
                    [NUMBER OF LEAVES] => 2,   (corresponding to leaves 100 and 101)
                    [childNodes] => Array ( 
                        [10] => Array ( 
                            [id] => 10, 
                            [parentId] => 1, 
                            [name] => Item 10, 
                            [childNodes] => Array ( 
                                [100] => Array ( 
                                    [id] => 100, 
                                    [parentId] => 10, 
                                    [name] => Item 100, 
                                    [childNodes] => Array ( ) 
                                ) 
                                [101] => Array ( 
                                    [id] => 101, 
                                    [parentId] => 10, 
                                    [name] => Item 101, 
                                    [childNodes] => Array ( ) 
                                ) 
                            ) 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
                [2] => Array ( 
                    [id] => 2, 
                    [parentId] => 9, 
                    [name] => Item 2, 
                    [NUMBER OF LEAVES] => 2,   (corresponding to leaves 200 and 201)
                    [childNodes] => Array ( 
                        [20] => Array ( 
                            [id] => 20, 
                            [parentId] => 2, 
                            [name] => Item 20, 
                            [childNodes] => Array ( 
                                [200] => Array ( 
                                    [id] => 200, 
                                    [parentId] => 20, 
                                    [name] => Item 200, 
                                    [childNodes] => Array ( ) 
                                ) 
                                [201] => Array ( 
                                    [id] => 201, 
                                    [parentId] => 20, 
                                    [name] => Item 201, 
                                    [childNodes] => Array ( ) 
                                ) 
                            ) 
                        ) 
                    ) 
                ) 
            ) 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 6):

this could solve your problem of "NUMBER OF LEAVES" for each node of my array. This entry should count ALL the leaves of all the subnodes of the node"

its from php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) 
        `$food = array('fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),
              'veggie' => array('carrot', 'collard', 'pea'));

```
     // recursive count
     echo count($food, COUNT_RECURSIVE); // output 8

     // normal count
     echo count($food); // output 2`
```

Comment: How many times over how many years have I iterated when I could have just passed a constant in.

Comment: This is not the real answer to the question, as it counts all nodes too. A leave is only the most outer part of a tree (has no children). So according to your example, counting the leaves should return 6 (orange, banana, apple, carrot, collard, pea)!

Comment: @marijnz0r I haven't programed for him just given an idea.Shared what I have on this topic.

Comment: Downvoted as this may mislead people, as stated by @marijnz0r. Edit your answer to state that and I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it easily as :

```
$leaves = 0;
array_walk_recursive($yourArray, function ($leaves) use (&$leaves) {
  $leaves++;
});
```

Example :

```
$foods = array(
  'fruits' => array('orange', 'banana', 'apple'),
  'veggie' => array('carrot', 'collard', 'pea')
);

$leaves = 0;
array_walk_recursive($foods, function ($leaves) use (&$leaves) {
  $leaves++;
});
echo $leaves; // will output 6
```

Comment: You don't need to declare `$leaves` as passing it by reference will automatically declare it.

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve this problem is using [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Example:

```
new LeaveCounter();

class LeaveCounter
  {
  public function __construct()
    {
    $this->sweet = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
    $this->fruits = array('sweet' => $this->sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon');

    $this->leaves = 0;

    array_walk_recursive($this->fruits, 'LeaveCounter::incrementLeaves');

    echo $this->leaves;
    }

  public function incrementLeaves($item, $key)
    {
    $this->leaves += 1;
    }
  }
```

This counts apple, banana and lemon, so it returns 3.

Answer (score 1):

Special case for an array with 2 levels:

```
$num = count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE) - count($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//find Totalaleaves
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($array),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

$ti = 0;
// NUMBER OF LEAVES keys
$tcount = 0;
// NUMBER OF LEAVES values
foreach ($iterator as $key => $item) {
    if (is_array($item) && $item['NUMBER OF LEAVES'] > 0) {
        $tcount = $tcount + $item['NUMBER OF LEAVES'];
        $ti++;
    }
}

echo "Totalleaveskeys=" . $ti;
echo "Totalleavesvalues=" . $tcount;
```

This solution work for the unlimited nested multidimensional arrays