# How to count numbers of keys in an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, count, numbers

I am using laravel 5, I need count the keys available inside every array index suppose for array[0] it has 7 keys, now I need the last key and before last key to compare which's value is bigger. how I can do using loop,as far I have tried.

**Please Note The inner keys are stored as object key=>value pair.**

```
foreach ($regions as $regions_key => $regions_value) {
        echo sizeof($regions_key)
    }
```

[image]

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Should be this: `count(array_keys($arr))`

Comment: The following url not solving the problem which I am facing in..

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284302/php-count-items-in-a-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: all your sub array size is same so you can do `$total_keys = count(array_keys($arr)) * count(array_keys($arr[0]))`

Comment: @Saty your last help is for 2D array but I am struggling in objects value count..

Comment: @TamaghnaBanerjee, did you try `$total_keys = count(array_keys($regions)) * count(array_keys($regions[0]))`??

Comment: @FrayneKonok after trying your snippet it returns with error **array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given**

Comment: Good, now try this one: `$regions = (array) $regions; $total_keys = count(array_keys($regions)) * count(array_keys($regions[0]))`.

Comment: I have tried your logic before you give, not worked..:(

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just count it within your loop:

```
$total = 0;
foreach($data as $sub_array) {
    $total += count($sub_array);
}
```

After the above iteration is done to find your counts, `$total` will hold your count.

[**Example/Demo**](https://eval.in/579932)

Comment: If it is mark as Duplicate than why answers??

Comment: @FrayneKonok Look at the duplicate - that's only for a 1 dimensional array, this question is 2D

Comment: it gives me outer array key,**I need inside one of each**.

Comment: I have supposed to get here to get help,if someone is not willing to help me then why this stackoverflow for while the question is not duplicate indeed,I have posted here after searching a long.

Comment: @TamaghnaBanerjee my example counts the internal arrays, as you asked for.

Comment: How is this?? `$total_keys = count(array_keys($arr)) * count(array_keys($arr[0]))`

Comment: @FrayneKonok that isn't a bad idea ;-) but you dunno if OP's array's all have the same amount as the first !

Comment: OP's sub array always the same size.

Comment: In this example yes @FrayneKonok

Comment: Guys! please keep your hands hold on..I feel the inside keys are stored as objects here.I was not sure while posting cause I am newbie in this technology.so @Darren your code is quite logical but not helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$countArr = array();
foreach ($regions as $regions_key => $regions_value) {
   $countArr[$regions_key] = count($regions[$regions_key]); // create array of length of sub array
}
echo max($countArr); // max — Find highest value
```

Comment: If it is mark as Duplicate than why answers??

Comment: where duplication marked??

Comment: What is the first comment in the question???

Comment: if marked as duplicated why you answered below that comment??? :)

Comment: You can check the time between those comments.....

Comment: ohh sorry couldn't mark that difference of milliseconds ;)

Comment: How about this?? `$total_keys = count(array_keys($arr)) * count(array_keys($arr[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

> To count the number of keys in an array. Try

```
$arr = Array
    (
        0 => 'hello',
        1 => 'there',
        2 => null,
        3 => null,
        4 => 3,
    );
var_dump(count($arr));
```

Comment: Thanks to every one. At last worked for me  `$iCount = 0;
  foreach ($regions as $regions_key => $regions_value) {
   foreach ($regions_value as $key => $value) {
    $iCount = count((array)$regions_value);
   }  
  }
  echo $iCount;`